# How to verify password hash ( hash_hmac, sha512 ) in php?

Tags: php, hmac, sha512

I need to convert VerifyPasswordHash method in C# to php. I have salt and stored_hash in DB for this user.

stored_hash = 0x0C3F6C5921CCD0305B2EDEDE1553B1DF55B87A9D55FEE3384A3833611BC40D106BBB48CCE1093AE35B9D0E3A1FE62E86186A6EC143BA00E53945E99C259B4913

salt=0xC62C5A645280DBCC615ED4A3E861D800B00A929856A9664B3AED50A06481ED19AFB09F74D3D7A9EA25327D93F23FDFBD2DE8CF3A75D65A3EA97290E0486F1F4322D2B5853AE6FE848E50355C35B62A993CF6689D9F9ABC861C5E7D88B099617E6A6C7792E285EFBB809FD69CD926C9BD9129AD1BE7DDB5DD459C2B9A2B945B31

Here is example in C#:

`

```
private bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] storedHash, byte[] storedSalt)
{
            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(storedSalt))
            {
                var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
                for (int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (computedHash[i] != storedHash[i])
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
}
```

Here is what I tried in PHP:
`

```
<?php
$password = 'Password202!';
$pass_hash = '0x0C3F6C5921CCD0305B2EDEDE1553B1DF55B87A9D55FEE3384A3833611BC40D106BBB48CCE1093AE35B9D0E3A1FE62E86186A6EC143BA00E53945E99C259B4913';
$pass_salt = '0xC62C5A645280DBCC615ED4A3E861D800B00A929856A9664B3AED50A06481ED19AFB09F74D3D7A9EA25327D93F23FDFBD2DE8CF3A75D65A3EA97290E0486F1F4322D2B5853AE6FE848E50355C35B62A993CF6689D9F9ABC861C5E7D88B099617E6A6C7792E285EFBB809FD69CD926C9BD9129AD1BE7DDB5DD459C2B9A2B945B31';

function VerifyPasswordHash($password,$pass_hash,$pass_salt){
$password_utf8 = utf8_encode($password);
$sig = hash_hmac('sha512', $pass_salt, $password_utf8, true);
echo base64_encode($sig);

}

VerifyPasswordHash($password,$pass_hash,$pass_salt);
```

I know that i need to compare $sig and stored_hash but they don`t even match.. Any help would be appreciated!

Expected result is successful comparison of $pass_hash and computed_hash. I simply need to verify password

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the content of the variables, which goes into the C# `VerifyPasswordHash(string, byte[], byte[])` method.

Comment: I don’t have an answer to your question, but I can tell you that almost all uses of `utf8_encode` are incorrect to the point that that function is being deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code, but you're almost there.

Firstly, drop the `utf8_encode()`. This rarely does what you expect and, as @Chris mentioned in a comment, the function has been deprecated and will be removed in the future.

According to [the manual](https://www.php.net/hash_hmac), the data to hash comes before the key (salt), so you have your parameters in the wrong order:

```
$sig = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, $pass_salt, true);
// $password first, then $pass_salt
```

Next, you're using `base64_encode`. That is not what you want, you're looking for a hexadecimal representation of the created signature. You're looking for `bin2hex()`:

```
echo bin2hex($sig);
```

However, this has the same effect as just passing `false` as the final argument to `hash_hmac` -- the `true` argument indicates you want a binary result, then you're turning it into hexadecimal representation. Passing `false` will return the hexadecimal notation instead of a binary result so you can skip the `bin2hex` step:

```
$sig = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, $pass_salt, false);
echo $sig;
```

The final problem is the notation of the salt. PHP does not use the `0x` prefix for hexadecimal strings. After a bit of trial-and-error, I also found that the correct way to calculate the hash is to actually use the binary representation of the hexadecimal salt-string (using `hex2bin`, the reverse of `bin2hex`):

```
function VerifyPasswordHash($password,$pass_hash,$pass_salt){
    // The substr() removes the leading "0x" from the salt string.
    $sig = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, hex2bin(substr($pass_salt, 2)), false);
    echo $sig;
}
```

For the values you provided, this outputs:

```
0c3f6c5921ccd0305b2edede1553b1df55b87a9d55fee3384a3833611bc40d106bbb48cce1093ae35b9d0e3a1fe62e86186a6ec143ba00e53945e99c259b4913
```

This matches your sample hash, if you'd uppercase it and put the redundant "0x" in front of it:

```
function VerifyPasswordHash($password,$pass_hash,$pass_salt){
    $sig = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, hex2bin(substr($pass_salt, 2)), false);
    $hash = '0x' . strtoupper($sig);
    
    return $hash === $pass_hash;
}
```

This returns [`true`](https://3v4l.org/GhZtG) for the given sample hashes.